# Suppress linebreak on file.write

Tags: python, file, line-breaks

When writing to a text file, some of the file.write instances are followed by a linebreak in the output file and others aren't.  I *don't* want linebreaks except where I tell them to occur. Code:

```
    for doc,wc in wordcounts.items(): 
        out.write(doc)             #this works fine, no linebreak
        for word in wordlist: 
            if word in wc: out.write("\t%d" % wc[word]) #linebreaks appear
            else: out.write("\t0")                      #after each of these
        out.write("\n")        #this line had mixed spaces/tabs
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

I should have taken a clue from how the code pasted into SO. For some reason there was a mixture of spaces and tabs in the final line, such that in TextMate it *visually* appeared outside the "for word..." loop—but the interpreter was treating it as part of that loop.  Converting spaces to tabs solved the problem.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Swapping those `write()` calls to `print` might help you visualize what is getting written to `out`.  Just make sure to use `print foo,` (trailing comma) so as to not add a line breaks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`file.write()` does not add any newlines if the string you write does not contain any `\n`s.

But you force a newline for each word in your word list using `out.write("\n")`, is that what you want?

```
    for doc,wc in wordcounts.items(): 
        out.write(doc)             #this works fine, no linebreak
        for word in wordlist: 
            if word in wc: out.write("\t%d" % wc[word]) #linebreaks appear
            else: out.write("\t0")                      #after each of these
            out.write("\n") #<--- NEWLINE ON EACH ITERATION!
```

Perhaps you indented `out.write("\n")` too far???

Comment: No, I don't want a newline on each iteration—I want a newline for each doc, with the words separated by tabs.

Comment: Ok, so your last out.write is intended too far, should be on the same level as the for word in wordlist -loop (i.e. in your question, 4 spaces left)

Answer (score 1):

You write a line breaks after every word:

```
for word in wordlist:
    ...
    out.write("\n")
```

Are these the line breaks you are seeing, or are there more additional ones?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to perform a `strip()` on each `wc[word]`.  Printing a single item from `wc` is would probably be enough to determine if there are already line breaks on those items that area causing this behavior.

Either that or the indentation on your final `out.write("\n")` is not doing what you intended it to do.

Comment: Latter is correct I think, the former is misleading as he is already doing "%d" % wc[word] which suggests that wc[word] are integers, not strings that can be .strip()ped...

Answer (score 0):

I think your indentation is wrong.

(also I took the liberty to make your if clause redundant and code more readable :)

```
for doc,wc in wordcounts.items()
   out.write(doc)
   for word in wordlist:
     out.write("\t%d" % wc.get(word,0))
   out.write("\n")
```