# Python is breaking a line in output

Tags: python, output, line, break

I have created a fairly large matrix (20x20) and want to save it to a file. Here's the part of the code that prints it:

```
file2=open('1.2.dat', 'w')
file2.write(str(hamil2[:][:]))    
file2.close()
```

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIZj8.png).

How can I fix it so I don't have a line break? I want each row of the matrix to be one line.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826400/suppress-linebreak-on-file-write

Comment: The only line breaks involved in this code are the ones already in `hamil2` (or the output of `hamil2.__str__` or `hamil2.__repr__`, as the case may be). `write` does not introduce a linefeed like `print` (by default) does. If you want more control over the format, you need to write your own function to use in place of `str`.